# output gets messed up when redirected to a file

Tags: c

Here is my code that is doing the printing that gets messed up. The output is fine when you display it to your screen (terminal). Unfortunately when you redirect it to a text file it gets messed up. It displays the null characters (^@) and Enquiry characters (^E). I have to use a for loop like this or my outputs gets messed up. I can't use the %s option or my output won't be in the way I need it.

```
FILE *input;
char line[80] = {0};
while(fgets(line, 80, input) != NULL)
{
    if((int)line[0] == 46)
    {
        //printf("You have a period \n");
        for(i = 31; i < 80; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", line[i]);
        }
        //printf(" ------------------------\n");
        memset(line, 0, 80);
        comment_flag = 1; 
    }
}
```

This is what I mean when I say redirect.

```
gcc *.c
./a.out > text_file
```

Comment: `#include <ctype.h>` and try `if (isprint((unsigned char)line[i]) || isspace((unsigned char)line[i])) printf("%c", line[i]);`

Comment: @pmg Can you explain the how and why this is working? I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: The condition in my condition only keeps printable characters (the `isprint()`) and space characters (`'\n'`, `'\t'`, ...). Other characters (`'\0'`, `'\x05'`, ...) are simply ignored for output.

Comment: @pmg any idea why Armali copied and pasted your answer when you explained this perfectly fine? I'm not familiar with the community wiki above his name.

Comment: Community wiki means he will not get reputation when his answer gets up voted or accepted (which was great of him to do as it really wasn't his answer). Also you really should accept an answer to your questions, and you can't accept a comment; so having this as an answer is good for the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <ctype.h>
```

and try

```
if (isprint((unsigned char)line[i]) || isspace((unsigned char)line[i]))
    printf("%c", line[i]);
```

The condition in my condition only keeps printable characters (the `isprint()`) and space characters (`'\n'`, `'\t'`, ...). Other characters (`'\0'`, `'\x05'`, ...) are simply ignored for output. –  pmg

Answer (score 0):

its probably silly, but if in your file, you see your null/empty array positions to be displayed with a special character (^@), then all  you have to do is to initialize your array with empty spaces, or better with '\0'.

You can do that even one time in the top of your programm, and if it doesn't work, try do that every time in the while loop, after printing the line into the file you want.

```
while(fgets(line, 80, input) != NULL)
{
    //Your code here
    for(i=0; i<80; i++)
        line[i]='\0';
}
```

Just remove the "memset" function and try this.

Comment: \0 = 0 = NULL so what you are telling me does nothing. I do that here `char line[80] = {0};` . This initializes my whole array to NULL. Take a look at an ascii table.

Comment: i know it's the same thing, but you never know where the problem is in C. When you have to do whith memory allocation, such as Arrays, you should look to the most silly thing, even if it looks the same, written with differet way.

Comment: C is frustrating like that.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to replace your output from screen to file, you just have to do this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( void )
{
   int i;
   FILE *file = fopen ( "test.txt", "r" );
   FILE *out = fopen ( "output.txt", "w");
   if ( file != NULL )
   {
      char line [ 128 ]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
      while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) /* read a line */
      {
        if((int)line[0] == 46)
        {
                //printf("You have a period \n");
                for(i = 31; i < 80; i++)
                {
                   fputs(line,out);
                }
        }
      }
      fclose ( file );
      fclose ( out );
   }
   return 0;
}
```

this writes to file properly, without any special characters displayed, and to your screen too, if you replace `fputs`, with `printf`, just like your answer in the top. If i got it right, that's what you want.

Comment: and if you want specific character, despite fputs, try  fputc(line[i], out);

Comment: But i think he is talking about redirection like in gcc<test.txt>output.txt.In the case of redirection gcc does the fputs() thing in the file.